# Which parts of MBA-13" mid-2011 can be upgraded?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, hardware-recommendation, repair, third-party

Which parts (if any) in Macbook Air 13" mid-2011 can be upgraded to either:

- an original part from a later version of Macbook Air/Pro
- or a third-party component which has a better performance/extra features?

Which are those replacement work really well (eg with no compatibility problems; last at least as long as the originals etc)?

E.g.: CPU, SSD, RAM, main board, wifi/BT card, speakers, USB 3.0, camera etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found so far:

- wifi: upgradable to 802.11 AC, with third-party [QuickerTek QCard2](http://www.quickertek.com/products/QCard2.html) (manufacturer gives dimensions: V1= 18.07mm x 39.9mm, but contradicting answers on whether it's compatible with MBA2011 13"). I asked for feedback on it in [a separate question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132486/); haven't tried it myself yet)

Answer (score 1):

You can also upgrade upgrade the SSD.

But be careful the connector used is a variant of the mini PCI Express connector.

With the Airport card it is the [only removable component](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Mid+2011+Teardown/6130) (worth changing) of the Macbook Air.

Comment: @ScottEarle and Matthieu, are there any Airport cards available that exceed the original performance? QCard which I mentioned above is not compatible with MBA2011-13" (will detail that later)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the SSD with another (faster or larger, or both) third-party SSD. Be aware that the SSD is not a regular SATA SSD, it is a mini-PCIe interface. There are several models [here (OWC)](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/SSD/OWC/Air-Retina/Apple-MacBook-Air-2011-Drive-Internal-Flash)

From earlier answers, it looks like you might be able to change the Airport card.

And that's pretty much it. Definitely can't change the RAM or CPU, or upgrade the battery, and there is no optical drive to do anything with.