# What Macbook have you tried QuickerTek QCard2 with?

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro, hardware, third-party

I wonder which versions of Macbook Air/Pro is [QuickerTek QCard2](http://www.quickertek.com/products/QCard2.html) (2-port) compatible with?

Anyone tried? With which Macbook? Did it work flawlessly? Any compatibility problems?

Answer (score 1):

Buyer beware since this is a total ripoff. I bought one of these overpriced MacBook Pro QCard2 – 3 Port for $149, which turned out to be a used late 2013 13″ MacBook Pro Retina airport/bluetooth card. iFixIt has these for $79.95, so I got ripped off by these bozos.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Back to the original question: which Macbook have you tried it with? Eg does it work with MBA 2011 13"?